# Apples and Rubia

Tags: blessing, rosh-hashanah-new-year, meal-seudah, fruits, vegetables

Why is it that Rosh Hashanah we make a Bracha Haetz on the Apple in Honey but no Hadamah is made on the vegetables IF THEY ARE both not directly part of the Seudah?

Comment: How do you know that this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak of sephardi custom, but there the custom is to make HaEitz on the pomegranate, adamah on something like the beans, and hakol on either the meat items(heart, lung, head).  This order can typically be found in any Sephardi Mahzor.  The two I am most familiar with are Ish Matzliah and Shulhan Melekhim.

Comment: Oh so Sefardim accentually make Brachos on all Items when you say sefardim does that mean all including syrians  Egyptians and Morocans?

Comment: To my knowledge yes.

Answer (score 2):

See [the desserts question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/brochos-on-desserts).  Common Ashkenazic practice is that fresh fruit warrants its own bracha.  But not vegetables.

Comment: Why is that the Halacha?

Comment: My understanding is that's understood as normal practice; fresh fruit is dessert, but salad and other vegetables are part of the meal.  Then again, my Rosh Yeshiva has a different mesora -- he makes a ha'adama on the carrot on top of his gefilte fish!

Comment: Quick explanation: fruit is more dessert-like than vegetables. You might have carrots, pickles or celery with your meal, but when was the last time you saw someone serve chopped apples?

Comment: @Shalom beat me by 30 seconds

Comment: My impression, based on this, is that the definition of "fruit" vs "vegetable" here is a culinary one, not halachic.  So strawberries for dessert get ha'adama; avocado in your salad doesn't get ha'etz.

Comment: The difference is that these are often done before the beracha on bread so including them in the "meal" is much more problematic.  How do you say that it is included in the motzei when the motzei hasn't been said yet?

Comment: @mekubal, you mean people aren't saying a bracha rishona on them?  That's really weird.  Or they say bracha rishona on them before hamotzi, then assume they'll be covered by birkat hamazon.

Comment: Some Sephardim have the custom to do the simanim after kiddush but before Hamotzi.  They are then covered by birkat hamazon under the idea that you only make the final blessing on the most Hashuv thing you have eaten, and numerous other complicated halakhic reasons.

Comment: @mekubal, yes the questions of what you can eat before hamotzee and still have covered by Birkat HaMazon are rather complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As brought in the footnote 35 [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Rosh_Hashana#cite_note-35),

> Chazon Ovadyah (p. 98) writes that one shouldn’t make a Bracha upon
>   the cooked vegetables because they’re considered as part of the meal.
>   Halichot Shlomo (1:18), however, writes that one should make a HaAdama
>   upon the gourd and exempt the other vegetables. To avoid all doubt,
>   Nitei Gavriel 29:18 writes that one should make a HaAdama on a banana.

It's interesting to note [Rabbi Tzadok](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2792/13811)'s insightful answer detailing an opposite sefardi minhag than the Chazon Ovadyah. Nonetheless, it seems the Halichot Shlomo would tell you to make a bracha on the vegetables which indeed aren't considered a part of the seudah.