# Bracha for fruit that is part of the meal

Tags: halacha, blessing, meal-seudah, fruits

Does fruit eaten as part of a bread meal (rather than as dessert) require its own bracha?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/having-dessert-in-mind possible duplicate or related?

Comment: I recall the hilchos Brachos book (not the Forst one) discusses different scenarios- fruit plates, appetizers, side dishes.  I do remember it saying that if your meal is a fruit plate, you do not make a bracha.  I don't have the book, and I'm not comfortable remembering anything else.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, related.  Not a duplicate.

Comment: Related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2685/15256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.If one eats (regular uncooked) fruit in a meal one should make a Bracha Rishona on the fruit but no Bracha Achrona([S”A 177:2](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%96_%D7%91))

2.A cooked dish made from fruit and is served as part of the main meal doesn’t require it’s own Bracha. For example, fruit soup, fruit salad, fritter, fruits mixed with chicken or meat, and fruit blintzes don’t require a Bracha during a meal(Vezot HaBracha (pg 76, chapter 8).

3.Fruits served as an appetizer requires a separate Bracha unless the fruit is known to whet one’s appetite(Vezot HaBracha (pg 77, chapter 8) in name of Rav Shlomo Zalman, see what he writes about Rav Elyashiv’s opinion on page 288, Birur 13(2):6.

Citrus fruits such as grapefruit are assumed to be eaten to whet one’s appetite whereas sweet fruits such as melon require a Bracha. However, some hold that even sweet fruits don’t require a fruit if eaten as an appetizer and therefore advise to exempt it by eaten a fresh fruit not being used as an appetizer or to have a fruit less than a Kezayit prior to a meal with intent to cover the fruit during the meal(Veten Bracha (Halachos of Brochos by Rabbi Bodner pg 93-4, chapter 5) writes that Rav Shlomo Zalman holds that a Bracha is required, whereas Rav Elyashiv argues.

4.There’s a doubt regarding compote and there’s what to rely to make a Bracha(Vezot HaBracha (pg 78, chapter 8).

5.If one has fruit as one’s main meal no Bracha is required for the fruit. However, it’s preferable to eat some fruit with bread in the beginning of the meal and then continue to eat fruit even without bread(Halacha Brurah 177:14.).

From [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Food_that_comes_during_a_meal#cite_note-18).