# Eating bread with jam, then eats only jam, would he recite a shehakol?

Tags: halacha, blessing, meal-seudah, fruits

If one is spreading jam on bread and eating it, and then eats only jam, without bread, would he make a shehakol on the jam, or would this be covered by the hamotzi?

Comment: possibly relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18954/170 (cc @mbloch )

Comment: You also have to ask if it needs an after bracha https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%95_%D7%90

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that it will depend on the reason for eating the jam. If it’s part of the meal and he’s eating it to satiate himself then it’s part of the bread meal.

The halacha states that something that is normally eaten together with bread, doesn’t require a bracha during a bread meal, even if it is eaten separately from the bread

Shulchan Aruch 177:1

> דהיינו דברים שדרך לקבוע סעודה עליהם ללפת בהם את הפת כגון בשר ודגים וביצים וירקות וגבינה ודייסא ומיני מלוחים אפי' אוכלם בלא פת אין טעונין ברכה לפניהם דברכת המוציא פוטרתן

However, if the jam is being eaten as a dessert or a sweet treat, it would require a bracha much like fruit and there like, mentioned later in the same Halacha:

> ואם הם דברים הבאים שלא מחמת הסעודה דהיינו שאין דרך לקבוע סעודה עליהם ללפת בהם את הפת כגון תאנים וענבים וכל מיני פירות (וע"ל סי' קס"ח סעיף ח') אם אוכל אותם בלא פת טעונין ברכה לפניהם דברכת המוציא אינה פוטרתן דלאו מעיקר סעודה הם

Answer (score 0):

[Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Ikar_and_Tafel#General_Guidelines_of_Ikar_and_Tofel) states that

> Once the initial situation of the food was a mixture and the two were
> eaten together, even if some Tofel remains without the Ikar, no new
> Bracha is needed. [4] However, if one added more Tofel after the Ikar
> was finished a new Bracha is needed. [5]

So, as long as the jam that he eats after the {bread & jam} was present initially, no new Bracha would be needed.