# Does flavored yogurt get its own blessing during a meal?

Tags: blessing, food

Does flavored yogurt qualify as "dessert" or is it considered part of the meal?

If it's dessert, would it require its own blessing?

What about plain yogurt?

Comment: @Shalom, mana does look like yogurt... :D

Comment: Just a guess. It is not baah machmas haseuda, not a food that is normally part of a meal of bread. So therefore would need its own bracha.

Comment: @user6591, in Turkey almost every dish consists of yogurt...

Comment: ah. T.y. now if a Turk asks this question i will know to answer him differently then anyone else in the world:) kefir anyone?

Comment: Is this a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/brochos-on-desserts or is the specific question about yogurt enough to justify it?

Comment: Avrohom Yitzhok, with ice cream some poskim hold that since it melts it's a liquid and hence no beracha. Yogurt however, stays at the same consistency at room temperature.

Comment: AniYodeya, is that (your last comment) the point of this question? I.e., you're asking about yogurt meant as dessert and you want to know whether it counts a solid? Then can you please [edit] that into the question? Or are you meaning something else here? It's an oddly specific question (flavored yogurt, not any yogurt), yet too general (you don't say whether it's a main course or a dessert, which, as you know, might make a difference), and completely lacking motivation. −1.

Comment: @Ani Yodeya IMHO yogurt that is stirred flows more easily - like melted ice cream.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be a dupe of what @AvrohomYitzhak linked to. Either way, read [this](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/18_devarim.html) to get a general sense of what's considered "desert". Excerpt:

> If one is already full, and he is only eating the deserts because he
>   enjoys its taste, he would have to make a new bracha on the item.
>
> Ice cream, sherbet, and candy all receive a separate bracha rishona.
>   However, many Sephardim hold that one should not make a Bracha on ice
>   cream in a meal.

So, if you are talking about plain "soft" yogurt (like Yoplait, Dannon, etc.) whether it's flavored or not, if you are eating it because of its taste after you have been full from the meal, you would need a bracha, based on above.

If by yogurt, you mean "frozen yogurt", this **may** be considered like ice cream (CYOR on this concept, as I couldn't guess on this one.) In that case, based on above reading, if you're Sephardi, you **might** be exempt.

Comment: DanF, The reason seafardim hold that ice cream gets no shehakol is because when it melts it turns to liquid; this isn't the case with yogurt.

Comment: DanF, what if you are not yet full and you have an apple to get more satiated?