# Do you need to make an additional blessing on yogurt eaten at the end of a bread meal?

Tags: food, meal-seudah, bread

If you washed and had bread, is yogurt eaten in the end of the meal covered by the homotzi?

Is there a distinction if is flavored (and usually with sugar) or plain (no sugar)?

Is there a distinction between greek yogurt (more thick) and plain yogurt (more liquid)?

Comment: Since this seems to be asking is the particular food considered dessert or part of the meal it is **not** a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/brochos-on-desserts?rq=1 While I would consider it as part of the meal (even if eaten at the end) I do not have proof of this.

Comment: @sabbahillel, is yogurt a regular food item, or a dessert item? Is it a liquid or a solid? (sefardim don't make brachot on any liquids - even if it has a potential to become a liquid - such as ice cream).

Comment: That is why I did not make it an answer. I **think** that it is a food item (not liquid - unlike ice cream) and not a dessert, but I do not have proof or a source.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking this topic depends on two things.
When you made hamotzi did you have in mind that you were going to eat yogurt?
And if you did, would you and most people consider this yogurt to be a dessert?

If you did not have it in mind at the beginning then you would need to make another Bracho, same as if it is considered a dessert.

Comment: Cannot provide sources, but someone (whom I believe to have sufficient knowledge of 'Brachot') told me that you must always make a bracha on a dessert, EVEN if you had it in mind. The truly deciding factor is whether it is a part of your meal or something tasty you wanted to add.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I said: If it would be considered a dessert then a Bracho would be needed.

Comment: I can see it now, I guess it was hard for me to understand your answer.